# how extract special data from numpy like R

Tags: numpy, bioinformatics

i stored a [bed file](http://asia.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/bed.html) in numpy like this:

```
>>> t
array([['chr1', '2488152', '2488153'],
       ['chr1', '2488397', '2488398'],
       ['chr1', '2491262', '2491417'],
       ..., 
       ['chrX', '153628144', '153628282'],
       ['chrX', '154292795', '154292796'],
       ['chrX', '154294899', '154294900']], 
      dtype='|S9')
```

usually, I do this job with R

```
library(dplyr)
filter(t, chrom=='chr1')
```

how can I get the same result with numpy? and is there any better way to stored bed file and extract the special lines I need?

thanks for any help.

Comment: you may want to have a look at `pandas`.

Comment: You might also be interested in [`pybedtools`](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a [boolean mask](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) by comparing the first column of every row in `t` to some value, and then apply that mask to `t`

```
>>> t[:,0]
array([b'chr1', b'chr1', b'chr1', b'chrX', b'chrX', b'chrX'], 
      dtype='|S9')
>>> mask = t[:,0]==b'chr1'
>>> mask
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> t[mask]
array([[b'chr1', b'2488152', b'2488153'],
       [b'chr1', b'2488397', b'2488398'],
       [b'chr1', b'2491262', b'2491417']], 
      dtype='|S9')
```